# Тень, произвольно меняющая цвет

Tags: css3, анимация

Такая задача: Есть див, а у него есть тень. И я хочу сделать эту тень анимированной, чтобы она меняла цвета. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли это сделать только при помощи CSS? Если нельзя то как это осуществить? Если не сложно, прикрепите источник, где можно об этом узнать поподробнее)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.block {
  margin: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation: shadowSpec 3s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes shadowSpec {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 4px #f00;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 4px #ff0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Ну например так

Comment: Это очень круто!! Вы мне очень помогли. Спасибо огромное!:)